# Excessive Queries in Django Role Permission

Tags: python, django

I am building a REST API with Django and Django Rest Framework. Its a application where teacher can create classroom. Classroom has lectures and other materials. These classroom can only be visit by the owner or the administrator. For controlling access to different endpoint I am using Django-Role-Permissions.

Whenever I'm trying to check permission using BasePermission from Django Rest Framework and Django-Role-Permission, I am receiving an excessive number of Database queries. For example, When I'm hitting List-Create Classroom endpoint, I am getting 40 Queries which is very weird.

Here's my Classroom model

```
from django.db import models

class Classroom(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    semester = models.ForeignKey(Semester, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='classrooms', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    archive = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

Here's my ListCreateClassroomAPIView

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView

class ListCreateClassroomAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ClassroomSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsAuthorizedToCreate)

    def get_queryset(self):
        if has_permission(self.request.user, 'view_classroom'):
            return Classroom.objects.all().select_related('teacher').select_related('teacher__employee_details')

        return Classroom.objects.filter(teacher=self.request.user).select_related('teacher'). \
               select_related('teacher__employee_details')

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        course = Course.objects.get(id=self.request.data.get('course'))
        semester = Semester.objects.get(id=self.request.data.get('semester'))
        serializer.save(teacher=self.request.user, course=course, semester=semester)
```

Here I'm trying to return all the classroom if the user has 'view_classroom' permission or return just the classroom the user owns.

The permission class:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission, SAFE_METHODS
from rolepermissions.checkers import has_permission

class IsAuthorizedToCreate(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return has_permission(request.user, 'create_classroom')
```

And SQL Traceback from Django Debug Toolbar
[SQL Queries from Django Debug Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCmIX.png)

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?